# Should the opinion-based close reason's description be adjusted for Graphic Design?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The Primarily Opinion-based (POB) close vote reason is well-known across the Stack Exchange network. It's used for questions where there are myriad valid solutions/answers to a problem/question, and reads thus:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

However, certain events (some [recent](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3238/how-should-the-process-for-mods-reopening-a-question-differ) and some [not](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/im-struggling-to-figure-out-why-people-vote-the-way-they-do-regarding-opinion)) have served to shine a light on the fact that Graphic Design is a *different site* than Stack Overflow. Specifically, since GD is at least as much an art as a science, the propensity for opinion (based on expertise or knowledge) in good answers or questions is much higher than that of Stack Overflow, despite the fact that what people find good design is largely a matter of taste.

In light of this, **should the verbiage of the POB close reason be adjusted** to indicate that even questions which sound opinion-based (such as ["When should I use X technique"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/93816/when-to-use-photos-or-illustrations-in-design)) don't automatically fall under the "close-worthy" category for critical GD readers?

Answer (score 7):

I don't see a problem with the wording at all. It doesn't say "All opinions are off-topic". It even begins with "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience"... which is exactly what we want here. Graphic Design is much more about experience and "art" than looking up a codified answer in some reference book.

If we want to discuss the on- or off-topicness of certain (e.g. "when should I use X technique"<sup>*</sup>) questions then we can do that. Discussing how the close reason is used in general is also a good idea... the wording itself though, I see no problem with.

It's also worth noting that the main close reasons are standard network-wide and not something moderators can change on a per-site basis. So it would need a Stack Exchange developer to make the change, which is unlikely to be happen without *very* good arguments to justify the development time.

---

<sup>*</sup> Which are the exact type of questions this site has struggled to get *more* of, instead of the constant "How to do X in Adobe Y" questions; not the kind of questions we want to be closing.